# Fusion Chart - How to define some onclick event in Column 2d chart after ploating

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using fusion chart and it is working perfectly fine in `ipad`. My code given below

```
<html>
  <head>        
    <title>My First chart using FusionCharts - Using JavaScript</title>         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts.js"></script>
  </head>   
  <body>     
    <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>   
     <div id="chartContainer1" style="margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: -22%;">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>   
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--

      var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Column2D.swf", 
                    "myChartId", "500", "300",  "0", "0");
var dataString ='<chart palette="2" caption="Industries" xAxisName="Days in Month" yAxisName="" labelDisplay="Rotate" showValues="0" decimals="0" formatNumberScale="0" bgcolor="FFFFFF" useRoundEdges="1" bgColor="FFFFFF,FFFFFF" showBorder="0">\n\
 <set value="20" label="Electric Power Generation" color="005C8E"/>\n\
 <set value="32" label="Industrial Processes" color="00759B"/>\n\
 <set value="12" label="Residential and Commercial Activities" color="0296D2"/>\n\
 <set value="20" label="Agriculture" color="40C7F9"/>\n\
 <set value="2" label="Waste Disposal" color="00496C"/>\n\
 </chart>';
  myChart.setXMLData( dataString );
 myChart.render("chartContainer"); 

    // -->  
    </script>      
  </body> 
</html>
```

Now i want to some other activities on click of column chart. For example like if i **click on Agriculture** which is having value 20 so based on this value i want some search activity or any other activity. Like if i click on Agriculture it will go to other event which i can define on click of Agriculture. Just let me know how to apply click event on Column 2d chart.

Below Code is working as per the requirement but only works on firefox .Please let me know any thing required for that to work on all browser and mobile devices as well.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Link Example</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="FusionCharts.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
      function myJS(myVar){
          window.alert(myVar);
      }
    // --></SCRIPT>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <div id="chartdiv" align="center">The chart will appear within this DIV. This text will be replaced by the chart.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var myChart = new FusionCharts("Charts/Column2D.swf", 
        "myChartId", "500", "300", "0", 
        "0");
       myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
       myChart.render("chartdiv");
    // --></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is Data.xml content

```
<chart caption='ABC Bank Branches' subCaption='(In 
      Asian Countries)' yaxislabel='Branches' xaxislabel='Country'>
    <set label='Hong Kong' value='235' link="JavaScript:myJS('Hong Kong,235');"/> 
    <set label='Japan' value='123' link="JavaScript:myJS('Japan, 123');"/>
    <set label='Singapore' value='129' link="JavaScript:myJS('Singapore, 129');"/> 
    <set label='Malaysia' value='121' link="JavaScript:myJS('Malaysia, 121');"/> 
    <set label='Taiwan' value='110' link="JavaScript:myJS('Taiwan, 110');"/> 
    <set label='China' value='90' link="JavaScript:myJS('China, 90');"/> 
    <set label='S. Korea' value='86' link="JavaScript:myJS('S.Korea, 86');"/> 
</chart>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to define links for individual data items using "link" attribute passed via <set> element. On click of the column data plot, it enables the end user to invoke any custom JavaScript function or drill down to other pages. Docs Link: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/DrillDown/LinkFormat.html

Comment: @Swarram Thanks for this help really helpful but the same code is not working on chrome and safari, ipad, android phone it is working only on firefox browser. what should i do for that.

Comment: @vishal_g I tested it work on Chrome. Can you paste your chart data with link attribute in it?

Comment: @N Bhargav I have updated the code , please check

Comment: @vishal_g It works in Chrome and Safari. Can you please try executing the sample from any local Webserver?

Comment: Ok that may me the reason, let me try it with webserver.